# If $N$ is a $4$ digit number $x_1x_2x_3x_4$, then prove that $\frac{N}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}\le1000$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

So $N=1000x_4+100x_3+10x_2+x_4$

$0<x_4\le 9$

$0\le x_3\le 9$

$0\le x_2\le 9$

$0\le x_1\le 9$

$0<{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}\le 36$

What should be my approach?

Comment: HInt:  you are trying to show that $$1000x_4+100x_3+10x_2+x_1≤1000x_4+1000x_3+1000x_2+1000x_1$$

Comment: You probably meeant $1 \leq x_4 \leq 9$, and also $1000 \leq N \leq 9999$, because the sum of $x_1$ to $x_4$ is clearly less than 36.

Comment: Multiply first inequality by 1000, second by 100, third by 10. Add up all the upper bounds to get your new max. But before you do that change the first inequality to $x_4$ between 1 and 9. (Lowest integer larger than 0 is 1). Add up all the mins to get a new minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:-**

$$1000x_1\le 1000 x_1$$$$100x_2\le 1000 x_2$$$$10x_3\le 1000 x_3$$$$x_4\le 1000 x_4$$

We can write these set of inequalities because $x_i$'s are nonnegative.